# How to stop for loop overwrtting variables

Tags: for-loop, overwrite

Hi thanks for your helps, im supposed to make a program that performs a text analysis of seeing which word is most frequently used. using an array to store the individual values works but how can i print it out so that it appears next to the letter instead just only printing out all the numbers in the array? The hashmap is where the letters are all stored in along with the amount of times they have been entered

```
float letter = 0;
float sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < Freq.length; i++){
    letter = Hmap.get(Freq[i]);
    sum[i] = letter / Freq.length; 
}
```

Comment: It would help to know what language you are using, but from the format, I'll guess Java.  You need to make `sum` an array e.g. `float[] sum = new float[Freq.length]`

and then in your loop do

    `sum[i] = letter / Freq.length;`

Then you will be able to see each division result in each member of the `sum` array.  You say that using an array "didn't work".  I think you might need to describe your context a bit more e.g. what is `Hmap` and how didn't it work (e.g. an Exception, or just unexpected output)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, im supposed to make a program that performs a text analysis of seeing which word is most frequently used. doing what you said above works but how can i print it out so that it appears next to the letter instead just only printing out all the numbers?

Comment: The hashmap is where the letters are all stored in along with the amount of times they have been entered

Comment: You need to show a bit more code - the definitions of `Freq` and `Hmap` - otherwise it's hard to know where the letters and counts are actually held.  Is `Freq` a list of letters (or words), or a list of frequencies?  I assume it's a list of letters / words.  If so - print out something like `System.out.println(Freq[i] + " " + sum[i]);`  A note - if this is how it works, it would be better to use more descriptive variable names e.g. `key_list` instead of `Freq` and `relative_frequency` instead of `sum`

Answer (score 0):

```
float[] sum = new float[Freq.length];

for(int i = 0; i < Freq.length; i++){ 
    sum[i] = Hmap.get(Freq[i]) / Freq.length; 
}
```

Although, I'm not sure I understand your question. What is sum supposed to hold?

Comment: Its supposed to hold the division of the frequency divided by total numbers of frequencies entered.   i could pm you the whole code if you don't mind?

Comment: So the sum of the frequencies divided by total frequencies, like an average?

Comment: @APengune Yes its supposed to perform a text analysis of seeing which word is most frequently used and it should all add up to 1